# Inconsistent Outlook Addin Event Firing

Tags: outlook, vsto, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

On my development machine I have the `FormInitializing` and `FormShowing` events firing before `RibbonLoad`.  I created a setup package in **VS 2010** and installed on a vanilla **Windows 7 Ultimate** with **Outlook 2010** installed.

The addin wasn't appearing on my meeting request form. So I setup remote debugger and to my astonishment the `RibbonLoad` is firing before the two form events mentioned above. A null exception is being throw b\c the code in the `RibbonLoad` relies on the `FormRegion` already being loaded. Can anyone offer any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no defined order for certain Outlook events - the **Ribbon UI** and the **Inspector UI** are completely different components, despite them both being display in the same window. The Outlook runtime may trigger Ribbon and Inspector events in different orders. It would be your job to synchronize the two events (*`RibbonLoad` and `FormInitializing`*) if you need some initialization done. You cannot assume that the ordering will always be the same.

I notice this same behavior when `ThisAddIn.Startup` fires before `ThisAddIn.CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`, but sometimes after depending on how Outlook triggers the sequencing. You can just use a static variable with sync locking to ensure your initialization code is only triggered once.

#### Here is an example I used to synchronize the `Startup` event with the `RibbonLoad` event:

```cs
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  static bool formInitialized = false;
  static readonly object padLock = new Object(); 

   private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       lock(padLock) { if (!formInitialized ) { InitializeForm(); } }
       // startup code
    }

   private void InitializeForm() 
   {
      // init code
      formInitialized = true;
   }

   protected override IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        lock(padLock) { if (!formInitialized) InitializeForm(); }
        // Create ribbon UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SilverNinja This is exactly what I did. At least my solution has now been verified. :)